# Windows file name length limit causes emails copied from outlook to vanish

Tags: backup, windows-7, outlook

In our server and workstation configuration, using Win7 - we set a maximum file name length limit (255 chars).

When copying emails from outlook to the file system for reserve, emails with subjects greater than 255 chars are simply dropped with no error message. (and silently kills the copying process - which is significant when 100 files are being copied)

Is this an error in our Win7 SOE config - or a bug in Outlook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a well known limitation of Windows OSes - files where the name and path exceed 255 characters are not handled properly by the OS.  Hit up Google for "path too deep" and "path too long" to see hordes of other people who've discovered the same limitation you have.

Best solution is probably not to copy out individual emails in the first place (you can archive those in a `.pst`, you know), followed by dropping them to the root of a drive (to shorten the length of the path), followed by viciously flogging users who abuse the subject line of an email badly enough to trigger a path too deep error (and renaming the emails as you move them, I guess).